# Split Data in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, split

Currently I'm facing with an issue and specially I don't know how to solve that. 
I have got a table:
--------------------------
| d.dasd |
| dasda.dasda |
| fdsfs.fsdf |
| fdsfdsaf.fdsafasdf |
| dasda.dasdasdas |
---------------------------

The thing is that I want to delete string after the "dot". I wrote a script in VBA:

```
Sub SplitText()

Dim Counter As Integer
Counter = 1
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim Temp As String
Dim Splited As String

Do While Counter <= LastRow

    Temp = Cells(Counter, 1).Value
    Splited = Split(Temp, ".")
    MsgBox Splited

Counter = Counter + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

But I have got issue in 'Splited = Split(Temp, ".")
The data after the dot should be deleted.

What should I do?

Comment: `Splited(0)` will give you the first part

Comment: It means I should do Splited = Split(Temp, ".")(0) ?

Comment: @MariuszAdamczewski yes

Comment: You need to define `Dim Splited As Variant` first, since you are trying to modify it's size in run-time using the `Split` (resulting in an array). And then you want to read the first element of the array, with `MsgBox Splited(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, if all you want is the text in front of the `.` then only change the one line:

```
Sub SplitText()

Dim Counter As Integer
Counter = 1
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim Temp As String
Dim Splited As String

Do While Counter <= LastRow

    Temp = Cells(Counter, 1).Value
    Splited = Split(Temp, ".")(0)
    MsgBox Splited

Counter = Counter + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It's working like the solution below. But here i dont have array. Thanks + 1

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
Sub SplitText()

    Dim Counter As Integer
    Counter = 1
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim Temp As String
    Dim Splited As Variant  '~~> Splited will be Variant and NOT string

    Do While Counter <= LastRow

        Temp = Cells(Counter, 1).Value
        Splited = Split(Temp, ".")  

        '~~> Run a loop on array and get all the items
        For i = LBound(Splited) To UBound(Splited)
            MsgBox Splited(i)
        Next

        Counter = Counter + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: It's working. I just added into the for, "Exit For" after the MsgBox because I wanted just first part of string. But its correct. Thank you, and have a nice day! + 1

Comment: Glad to help :)